# openSUSE Tumbleweed HyperV not installing

Tags: linux, hyper-v, failed-installation, opensuse

I have downloaded latest openSUSE Tumbleweed iso and tried to install it in my Hyper-V. Everytime the installer is stopping after the message "Loading initial ramdisk".
Installer is not all starting and I could not find any help in online. Could you please help me on this?

Regards,
Manohar

Comment: There is not enough information in your question. Like: What host is used? What VM type is used (Gen1 or Gen2)? How much memory does the VM have, and is ballooning enabled for that VM?